# What is the "#fbml=1" doing in <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"> ? URLs don't have hash but without it, it won't work

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-like

What is the `#fbml=1` doing in `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">` ?  (this is the official Facebook Like button code obtained from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ )

Also, in Fiddler, I see it simply doing a

```
GET /en_US/all.js HTTP/1.1
```

But try to remove `#fbml=1`, and the page won't show the Facebook Like button.  What is the mechanism going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashtags are never sent to the server, but Javascript can access it via `location.hash` or, when it's used in a script tag, access the tag's `src` attribute.

This is most likely the code responsible for it:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    var a = /(connect.facebook.net|facebook.com\/assets.php).*?#(.*)/;
    FB.Array.forEach(document.getElementsByTagName('script'), function (d) {
        if (d.src) {
            var b = a.exec(d.src);
            if (b) {
                var c = FB.QS.decode(b[2]);
                FB.Array.forEach(c, function (f, e) {
                    if (f == '0') c[e] = 0;
                });
                FB.init(c);
            }
        }
    });
    if (window.fbAsyncInit && !window.fbAsyncInit.hasRun) {
        window.fbAsyncInit.hasRun = true;
        fbAsyncInit();
    }
}, 0);
```

Comment: and this is using the `<script>` tag's `src` attribute to do it... the second way...

Comment: actually, in this case, the `location.hash` won't be able to use it, as the URL on the browser doesn't have the hash -- only the Javascript path has it.  That's why it is done using the `src` of the `<script>` tag... this may be the only way it can be accessed?  Actually, this is like a smart way to pass parameter to the `.js`. file... it can use `all.js?foo=1` but then it will work the server more because each time with a different parameter, the server will need to provide the file again even if it was previously loaded as `all.js` and the content is all the same.